# In Flutter, is there a way to determine the user's skin color settings for their emojis?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, flutter-dependencies

We're creating an app that uses custom icons that we made in Figma, some of which are faces, waving hands, etc. As of now, we're just using a default yellow color, but I think it would be a nice touch if we could just use the same settings as what the user has for their device. Does Flutter have a way of accessing and viewing those settings?

So far, I've looked around stackoverflow and GitHub issues, but I couldn't find anything at all.